# In ggplot2, why can't I put two panel into one plot using the ggplot2 wiki method (dummy facet variable)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

**In ggplot2, I tried to put two plots which have the same x-axis into one separated-panel plot by Hadley's website : https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Align-two-plots-on-a-page**

**This is the proposed code:**

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- seq(1992, 2002, by=2)

d1 <- data.frame(x=x, y=rnorm(length(x)))
xy <- expand.grid(x=x, y=x)
d2 <- data.frame(x=xy$x, y=xy$y, z= jitter(xy$x + xy$y))

d1$panel <- "a"
d2$panel <- "b"
d1$z <- d1$x

d <- rbind(d1, d2)

p <- ggplot(data = d, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y))
p <- p + facet_grid(panel~., scale="free")
p <- p + layer(data= d1,  geom = c( "line"), stat = "identity")
p <- p + layer(data=d2, mapping=aes(colour=z, fill=z),  geom =
c("tile"), stat = "identity")
p
```

But I something went wrong when I want to add more plots with different y values in the upper panel.

Here is my data:

```
attitude <- c("Hostile", "Rude", "Praising", "Commanding", "Insincere", "Polite", "Joking",   "Suggesting", "Irony", "Serious", "Friendly", "Sincere", "Neutral")
order<-c(12,13,8,7,1,11,2,3,4,6,10,9,5)
min<-c(0.249746688,0.105828885,0.170151929,0.20565908,-0.09135461,0.192402573,0.023005096,0.011312206,-0.044620705,0.072541529,0.089307133,0.165717303,0.110689225)
max<-    c(2.2885,2.4161,1.8467,1.7535,1.6409,2.0631,1.6517,1.7195,1.5322,1.8345,2.2395,2.1871,1.5551)
mean<-c(1.100819511,1.128603777,0.873735105,0.843770095,0.659525513,0.972857404,0.681777825,0.693606814,0.696879247,0.82999014,0.955312553,0.94512688,0.730545923)
SpRate<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

d1 <- data.frame(attitude, order, min, max, mean, SpRate)

attitude <- c("Hostile", "Rude", "Praising", "Commanding", "Insincere", "Polite", "Joking", "Suggesting", "Irony", "Serious", "Friendly", "Sincere", "Neutral")
order<-c(12,13,8,7,1,11,2,3,4,6,10,9,5)
min<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
max<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
mean<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
SpRate<-c(0.1505,0.154,0.1615,0.1615,0.172,0.1725,0.1765,0.177,0.1845,0.1905,0.1905,0.1945,0.1955)

d2<-data.frame(attitude, order, min, max, mean, SpRate)

d1
d2
```

**In fact, I want to draw a plot like in the website which the upper panel shows three point bar with different y value (min, mean, max), and the lower panel shows a bar plot where y=SpRate, but it seems doesn't work, why?**

**Here is my code:**

```
library (ggplot2)
d1$panel <- "a"
d2$panel <- "b" 
d <- rbind (d1, d2)

p <- ggplot (data=d, mapping = aes(x=order))
p <- p+facet_grid (panel~., scale="free")

#upper panel
p <-p+ layer (data=d1, aes(y=min), geom = c("point"), stat="identity")
p <-p+ layer (data=d1, aes(y=max), geom = c("point"), stat="identity")
p <-p+ layer (data=d1, aes(y=mean), geom = c("point"), stat="identity")


#lower panel
p<-p+ layer (data=d2,  aes(y=SpRate), geom = c("bar"), stat="identity")

# not work, why?
p
```

Comment: for info, hadley is [not responsible](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Align-two-plots-on-a-page/_history) for the code on this particular wiki page. I'm changing the title accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this using `geom_point()` and `geom_bar()` and then it works

```
ggplot(data=d,aes(x=order))+facet_grid(panel~.,scale="free")+
      geom_point(data=d1,aes(y=min))+
      geom_point(data=d1,aes(y=max))+
      geom_point(data=d1,aes(y=mean))+
      geom_bar(data=d2,aes(y=SpRate),stat="identity")
```

Comment: @PingTang Please don't add your NEW question to my answer!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to add my code in a new comment.